# Is this possible for sum(base_total - total_discount) in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, api, sum

My SQL query is

```
SELECT SUM(base_total - total_discount) 
FROM orders 
WHERE created_at LIKE '2020-09-18%' 
AND customer_id = 9
```

so how to write this query in laravel

Comment: I would start with how to write this query in sql

Comment: Is `created_at` a DATETIME column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes

Comment: @Strawberry this is a SQL query I want it in Laravel thanks

Comment: I think @Strawberry point is that it is not a good query, first you should look at how you would normally search on a date in SQL

Answer (score 0):

My Laravel query for this is `Order::where('created_at','like','2020-09-18%','and','customer_id','=','9')->sum('base_total','-','total_discount');` where Order is model